# Angular service/factory return after getting data

Tags: json, angularjs, q

I know this has something to do with using $q and promises, but I've been at it for hours and still can't quite figure out how it's supposed to work with my example.

I have a .json file with the data I want.  I have a list of people with id's.  I want to have a service or factory I can query with a parameter that'll http.get a json file I have, filter it based on the param, then send it back to my controller.

```
angular
  .module("mainApp")
  .controller('personInfoCtrl',['$scope', '$stateParams', 'GetPersonData', function($scope, $stateParams, GetPersonData) {

    $scope.personId = $stateParams.id; //this part work great

    $scope.fullObject = GetPersonData($stateParams.id);
    //I'm having trouble getting ^^^ to work.  

    //I'm able to do
    //GetPersonData($stateParams.id).success(function(data)
                 //                      { $scope.fullObject = data; });
    //and I can filter it inside of that object, but I want to filter it in the factory/service
  }]);
```

Inside my main.js I have

```
//angular.module(...
//..a bunch of urlrouterprovider and stateprovider stuff that works
//
}]).service('GetPersonData', ['$http', function($http)
{
  return function(id) {
      return $http.get('./data/people.json').then(function(res) {
        //I know the problem lies in it not 'waiting' for the data to get back
        //before it returns an empty json (or empty something or other)
        return res.data.filter(function(el) { return el.id == id)
      });
    }
}]);
```

The syntax of the filtering and everything works great when it's all in the controller, but I want to use the same code in several controls, so I'm trying to break it out to a service (or factory, I just want the controllers to be 'clean' looking).

I'm really wanting to be able to inject "GetPersonData" to a controller, then call GetPersonData(personId) to get back the json

Comment: Did you check your console and see errors. You seems to be having syntax error in your code. `.service('GetPersonData', ['$http', function($http){
  return function(id) {
     return $http.get('./data/people.json').then( function (res) {
           return res.data.filter(function(el) { return el.id == id });
      });
}}]);`  return statement in your filter function is off

Comment: @PSL That probably is from me trying to do a minimal runnable code for the question.  It's not throwing an error, just returning an empty object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to be syntax issue in your filter function in the service.

```
.service('GetPersonData', ['$http', function($http){
  return function(id) {
     return $http.get('./data/people.json').then( function (res) { 
           return res.data.filter(function(el) { return el.id == id });
      });
}}]);
```

But regarding the original issue you cannot really access the `success` property of the `$q` promise that you are returning from your function because there is no such property exist, It exists only on the promise directly returned by the http function. So you just need to use the `then` to chain it through in your controller.

```
 GetPersonData($stateParams.id).then(function(data){ $scope.fullObject = data; });
```

If you were to return `return $http.get('./data/people.json')` from your service then you will see the http's custom promise methods `success` and `error`.

Comment: Lame, that's kinda what I was trying to avoid.

Right now I'm trying to make two services, one to grab the ajax, another to wait for the ajax then filter on it

Comment: @charmonkie What is lame? Thats  the beauty of using promises... You can chain them through altering the data on the previous chain...

Comment: The having to put the then + filter stuff in the controller.

Comment: @charmonkie Yes you can move it to your service which is perfectly fine... But i did not understand your statement `one to grab the ajax, another to wait for the ajax then filter on it`

Comment: I was thinking I could use one service to retrieve the json. then another service to have the .then or .success function, the controllers would call the second function, which would handle the success stuff, so the controllers could just call @scope.obj = GetObj(id);

Comment: @charmonkie You could do that as well, but why do you want to separate out the mapping logic alone to a separate function. For doing that you would need your serviceB to chain through ServiceA's promise and return its owne promise which your controller will chain through.